# Powershell commandlet to write code within a method

Tags: c#, powershell, metaprogramming, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have been writing a couple of powershell funcions to automate code generation for ASP.NET MVC 4, I am using cmdlets from [MvcScaffolding](http://mvcscaffolding.codeplex.com/) and they are being very helpful, but there is one thing missing, I would like to be able to write code within a method. For example, I am using the following to write code within a class:

```
$class = Get-ProjectType Product
Add-ClassMember $class "public string Description { get; set; } "
```

The command above works fine, but the code goes to the class scope and I would like to place it inside a specific method, such as the class constructor for example.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found any solution?

Comment: Hi Nazemian, no I haven't found any solution.